# unknown attribute X, but X is not in argument of update_attributes in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, update-attributes

I am trying to set object's field in the form with accept_nested_attributes. However in the controller when I do :

```
@device.update_attributes(params[:device])
```

I get :

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError
"unknown attribute: device_id"
```

but device_id, which is an attribute of other non-related model, is not included in params.
Params are like following.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Xja5GCNRutpZn2c4wKeSx0KO6sNEzh09kWmPQ0/0Hys=",
 "id"=>"5",
 "device"=>{"routes_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"",
 "origin_attributes"=>{"name"=>"",
 "lat"=>"",
 "lng"=>""},
 "destination_attributes"=>{"name"=>"",
 "lat"=>"",
 "lng"=>""}}}},
 "commit"=>"Create Device"}
```

What can be thought as a cause.
Here are my codes.

view

```
<%= form_for @device, :url => {:action => "do_compose"}, :method => :post do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
     <%= select_tag(:id, options_for_select( Device.all.collect{|d| [d.name + "/" + d.get_driver().name, d.id] } ),:prompt=>"select a device") %>                                 
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= render partial:"routes/nested_routes_form", locals: {route_object:@device.get_route(), parent_form:f} %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
  def do_compose
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @device.update_attributes(params[:device])
        format.html { redirect_to @device, notice: 'Device was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: comopse }
      end
    end
  end
```

model

```
  class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :destination_attributes, :origin_attributes, :waypoints, :driver_id
    has_many :waypoints
    has_one :origin, :class_name=>"Origin"
    has_one :destination, :class_name=>"Destination"
    belongs_to :device
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :origin, :destination, :waypoints
  end

  class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :id, :name, :password
    attr_accessible :device_driver_bind_attributes, :drivers_attributes, :routes_attributes, :current_location_attributes
    has_many :drivers, through: :device_driver_bind
    has_many :device_driver_bind, dependent: :destroy
    has_one :current_location, :class_name => "CurrentLocation"
    has_many :routes
    has_many :origins, through: :routes
    has_many :destinations, through: :routes
    has_many :waypoints, through: :routes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :routes, :current_location, :device_driver_bind
  end
```

Comment: You might want to check Route for a missing :device_id column. AR expects to be able to set this with `accepts_nested_attributes_for :routes`, to satisfy `belongs_to :device`

Comment: That was it! Such an easy mistake.. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I'll turn this into a full answer then so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be the problem in your select_tag, try this:

```
<%= f.select(:id, options_for_select( Device.all.collect{|d| [d.name + "/" + d.get_driver().name, d.id] } ),:prompt=>"select a device") %>
```

Comment: It's f.select, to be exact :=)

Comment: Thank you for response, but didn't work. I changed like @device = Device.find(params[:device][:id]) in do_compose action concurrently, and getting the same error..

Comment: By the way, some of the attributes of Device object at the time of doing "@device = Device.find(params[:id])" are already set. And I'm trying to set the rest of attributes by
    @device.update_attributes(params[:device]).

Answer (score 0):

```rb
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError
"unknown attribute: device_id"
```

looks like it's due to a missing column on Routes.

ActiveRecord expects to be able to set this with `accepts_nested_attributes_for :routes`, to satisfy `belongs_to :device`.